# How to post a form from HTML into Node.js file

Tags: node.js

I've a HTML file named index.html, and a Node.js files named server.js and logic.js.

server.js is reponsible for creating the server and loading index.html file. The HTML file displays a form asking for any action(ex: username), then it posts this data to the logic.js file which prints this user name.

how could it be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, without seeing any of your code or knowing what framework you're using, it will be hard to be specific, but you'll want to

- Render some HTML that includes a form on HTTP GET

  - this is the simplest part. Just write a simple document with a  and some  tags. I assume you already have some web server that does this.
- Listen for POST requests.

  - This is different from a GET and your server will likely have a different function to handle that request (because the logic is different).
- Handle the POST requests

  - here you'll just want to pull out the name from the POST data and print it (or do whatever you want).

I recommend using [expressjs](http://expressjs.com) for this since you probably don't want to write all of the code that handles the web server. With this framework, rendering HTMl is as simple as

```
app.get("/", function(request, response) { res.send(some_html); });
```

and handling the POST would be as simple as

```
app.post("/endpoint", function(request, response) { console.log(request.query.name); });
```

edit: to answer your question, it really isn't that hard to spread out the logic for handling multiple pages throughout separate files. What I normally do is have a server.js that sets up everything, and then will include the other files that handle the logic for other pages.

For example, if your app might be laid out like

```
server.js
/modules/
/modules/index.js
/modules/user.js
/modules/posts.js
public/index.html
public/user.html
public/posts/html
```

and server.js would include all of the files inside the modules directory, one of them might look like

### index.js

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  render("index.html");
});
```

### user.js

```
app.get("/user", function(req, res) {
render("user.html");
});
```

## post.js

```
app.get("/post", function(req, res) {
render("post.html");
});
```

Comment: Actually I don't use expressjs but I think I will. Could I know if these lines of code written in a single file or it could be distributed through many files.

Comment: Just edited my answer in response to your comment. I hope I understood your meaning. In general, I try to take the logic for my apps and take the parts that are specific to handling a section of the app and putting in a separate file from everything else. Node doesn't always make this easy with the commonjs module system, but once you see a few good design patterns, it becomes a lot easier. I recommend looking at some of the good node projects on github to see how they handle dependencies in their projects.

Comment: Thanks very much. I wish I could vote for your answer more than once. :)